# How to calculate the Standard Deviation in a Dataframe with different objects in Python

Tags: python, group-by, standard-deviation

I have a dataframe of each recorded position for a group of animals, where:

- `ANIMAL N°` represents a different animal
- `X` is the location of the animal along the x-axis,
- `Y` is the location of the animal along the y-axis:

  ```
  ANIMAL N°       X        Y      
   11           2474  2704.30        
   4            2603  2992.07        
   11           2806  2716.43      
   6            3262  2977.39        
   11           2907  2960.50 
   6            2474  2704.30      
   4            2603  2992.07        
   11           2806  2716.43      
   6            3262  2977.39        
   11           2907  2960.50
  ```

Through this code, I have calculated the median of `X` and `Y` in order to provide a general idea of the location for each animal:

```py
Df['Median X'] = Df['X'].groupby(Df['ANIMAL N°']).transform('median')
Df['Median Y'] = Df['Y'].groupby(Df['ANIMAL N°']).transform('median')
```

And it gives me this output:

```
ANIMAL N°       X        Y    Median X  Median Y  
 11           2474  2704.30   2470.38   2707.44     
 4            2603  2992.07   2610.29   2978.06     
 11           2806  2716.43   2470.38   2707.44   
 6            3262  2977.39   3255.30   2968.06     
 11           2907  2960.50   2470.38   2707.44
 6            2474  2704.30   3255.30   2968.06    
 4            2603  2992.07   2610.29   2978.06     
 11           2806  2716.43   2470.38   2707.44   
 6            3262  2977.39   3255.30   2968.06     
 11           2907  2960.50   2470.38   2707.44
```

Now I would calculate the *Standard Deviation* for each Animal between the `X`/`Y` and `Median X` / `Median Y`, in order to understand the precision of the detected positions.

I tried this code, but it doesn't work:

```py
Df['StDv X'] = Df['Median X'].groupby(Df['ANIMAL N°']).std(Df['X'])
Df['StDv y'] = Df['Median y'].groupby(Df['ANIMAL N°']).std(Df['Y'])
```

Comment: Can [Calculate Standard Deviation of Multiple Columns](https://www.statology.org/pandas-standard-deviation/) within DataFrame resolve your problem? There was an answer using this method when I checked 10 hrs ago, but now it has been deleted.